# Why is my frame not recognizing Swipe Gesture?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, frame

I wanted to add a swipe `gesture recognizer` to a frame. So when the user keep his finger on the `Frame`, he could slide it to a dustbin and delete it.
However, it seems that the swipe gesture is not being recognized since i made debug and the `event handler` was not fired.

Xaml Code:

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,100,0,0" Spacing="10" x:Name="MeusObjectivosLayout">
                    <Label Text="Meus Objectivos" IsVisible="True" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black"/>
                    <CollectionView x:Name="lista">
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="1"/>
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Padding="0,5,0,0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="#00b9ff" CornerRadius="4">
                                        <local:CustomEditor Completed="LabelObjectivo_Completed" Text="{Binding Titulo}" x:Name="labelObjectivo" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Down" Swiped="FrameSwiped"/>
                                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Frame>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </StackLayout>
```

Event handler:

```
        private void FrameSwiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
        {
            var frame = sender as Frame;
            frame.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0, 100, frame.Width, frame.Height), 1250, Easing.SpringIn);
        }
```

PS: How can i implement something like unninstalling an app on android ? Keeping finger on the app and slide to a dustbin icon.

Comment: Your swipe gesture probably isn't working because it's inside a `CollectionView`, which is still in preview. I'd try your view outside of the collectionview so you know if it's a problem with the swipegesture on the frame or with being inside the collectionview itself.

Comment: @Nick Just tried and still didnt work.

Comment: I take it even outside of the collectionview it didn't work. If that is the case try changing it from a `Frame` to a `ContentView` with it removed from your collectionview to see if there is any difference.

Comment: I tried with `Frame` outside of the project and it worked.

Comment: Okay yeah, then it's definitely because it's inside something that scrolls that is effecting the `SwipeGestureRecognizer`. It looks like there is a [bug report](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4628) for a similar issue on Android.

Comment: So instead of collection view, i should do something static ? Like, adding a new frame on code behind ?

Comment: Chances are that won't make a difference. You'll either have to find a different way to accomplish whatever you're trying to with your swipe gesture, wait until the issue is resolved, or go fix it in XF itself.